# The legend of Rashi's 4 lines

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rashi

There is a known legend among Talmudists that each Amud has four lines of Rashi before the beginning of the text of the Talmud to hint to a student to review the Amud four times before continuing. I'm just wondering: does anyone know a source for this peculiar legend???

Comment: Is there a source for reviewing four times in general?

Comment: @shmosel ,masheches eruvin...

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2016/11/20/why-are-there-4-lines-of-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-and-%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99-that-seperates-from-the-gemara/

Comment: This post is hidden. You deleted this post 12 hours ago.
I may have heard something like this quoted from קריינא דאגרתא. Although I think it's more of a symbological attribution to that printing method; for, if I recall correctly, facsimiles of older Gemaras don't have those four lines you mention. This doesn't diminish the significance of reviewing four times.